# magento 2 custom cart field error

Tags: magento2.3.4

Hi am getting error which says unable to add this item to your cart

**my 1st observer**

```
    <?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;
    private   $_jsonSerializer;
    
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer
)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_jsonSerializer    = $jsonSerializer;
}
 
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
     
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $additionalOptions = array();
        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
            $additionalOptions = (array) $this->_jsonSerializer->unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }
        $post = $this->_request->getParam('additional_options');
        if(is_array($post))
        {
            foreach($post as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key == '' || $value == '')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $additionalOptions[] = [
                    'label' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                ];
            }
        }
        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0)
        {
            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => $this->_jsonSerializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));

            $observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->_jsonSerializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
        }

    }
}
```

**2nd observer**

```
  <?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $quoteItems = [];
    private $quote = null;
    private $order = null;

     private     $_jsonSerializer;

      public function __construct
      (
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer
      )
                {
                $this->_jsonSerializer    = $jsonSerializer;
                }
   
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $this->order = $observer->getOrder();
        foreach($this->order->getItems() as $orderItem)
        {
            if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
            {
                if($quoteItem = $this->getQuoteItemById($orderItem->getQuoteItemId())){
                    if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                    {
                       
                        if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                        }
                        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0)
                        {
                            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                            $options['additional_options'] = $this->_jsonSerializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function getQuoteItemById($id)
    {
        if(empty($this->quoteItems))
        {
          
            foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item)
            {
                
                if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                {
                    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->quoteItems))
        {
            return $this->quoteItems[$id];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Error log when i add items to cart**

```
[2020-09-30 11:59:46] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error [] []
[2020-09-30 11:59:46] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error [] []
[2020-09-30 12:05:00] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error [] []
[2020-09-30 12:05:01] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error [] []
```

**my phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
       <div class="field sender name required">
    <label class="label" for="sender">
      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('From')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field to required">
    <label class="label" for="to">
      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('To')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="field message required">
    <label class="label" for="message">
      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Message')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Your Message')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
    </div>
</div>
 


        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <br>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your construct with below code in `CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php` file

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $jsonSerializer
)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_jsonSerializer    = $jsonSerializer;
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: what is the change ?

Comment: You forgot to define $request

Comment: yes i figured it and i was using it lol

Comment: dude same error again  Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

Comment: Can you please update your code in question so I can check the issue.

Comment: wait a min am on it

Comment: updated please check